# Java logger Spring

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I would like to use the logger and set its properties, but does not want to create in each object class Logger my goal is to do:
create a beans in the Spring ,create properties file how  can  I use annotations ,is possible to do it ?

Comment: The aim of making one logger per class (not per object) is enabling finely grained configuration at runtime. What keeps you from follofing good practice?

Comment: i need to change properties for logger i mean disabled output on console etc,  so i have a lots of classes and its stupid declare in every classes private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Class.class.getName());

Comment: 1) Logging sinks configuration should be controlled by maintenance staff via configuration rather by code developer programmatically. 
2) You still have one line of code in each class one way or another. But lookup in spring context is far more fragile than LogginFactory.getLogger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it ,

```
<bean id="log" class="org.apache.log4j.Logger" factory-method="getRootLogger"/>

<bean id="app" class="com.App" >
    <property name="logger" ref="log"/>
</bean>
```

And in your class ,

```
App bean = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app.xml").getBean(App.class);
```

with basic spring DI